# sql distinct duplicates cross values

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, distinct

I am trying to tidy up a database removing duplicates.
Let's say I have a database that looks like this one

```
Date        | Value1 | Value2
01/01/2018       A        B    
01/01/2018       B        A
02/01/2018       A        B
```

In this case, according to my needs, the first two rows are identical, so I would like to drop one (let's say the second one). If I use SELECT DISTINCT it won't drop it because they are, in fact, different.

Is there an easy procedure to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exists` operator to find (and delete!) them:

```
DELETE FROM mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.value1 = b.value2 AND
                      a.value2 = b.value1 AND
                      a.value1 < b.value1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
create table t(date,value1,value2);
insert into t values
('01/01/2018','A','B'),
('01/01/2018','B','A'),
('02/01/2018','A','B');

select distinct date,min(value1,value2) value1,max(value1,value2) value2 from t;
```